# Why I can't get the result of 'r' in the equation with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I've defined the 'r' as the symbolic variable in the equation, but still get the error as "name 'r' is not defined"

```
from sympy import symbols, solve
#Total money you loan
A=1690*74
#Total month you need to pay
m=37
#Every month the total money you need to pay
x=4000
# r is the monthly interest rate
r=symbols('r')
expr=(A*r*(1+r)**m)/((1+r)**m-1)-x
sol=solve(expr,dict=True)
print(sol)
```

Run the file and get nothing feedback. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: `r = symbols('r')` is the usual way of defining a symbol variable.  In `expr`, `r`, `m` and `x` are Python variables, not Symbols.  Keep in mind the `sympy` runs in Python.  It's not a standalone language.

Comment: So what is the problem again, that `r` is not defined or that you get no result?

Comment: His edit has changed the question.  When I try it in a `isympy` session the `solve` takes forever.

Comment: It finished with a `m=12`, but the result is a list of 12 `CRootOf` expressions.  Explore some alternative `solve` options with a much smaller problem.  Other assumptions on `r` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you are trying to solve is (or can be rearranged to) a polynomial of order 37:

```
                37       
125060⋅r⋅(r + 1)         
────────────────── - 4000
         37              
  (r + 1)   - 1
```

SymPy is trying hard to find an analytic solution to that but in general analytic solutions are only guaranteed to exist up to order 4 (and even then can be absurdly complicated).

I think what you really want here is a numeric solution so `nsolve` should do the job:

```
>>> nsolve(expr,r,1)
0.00915469685511422
```

As a fractional monthly interest rate that corresponds to an annualised rate (x100x12) of ~11%.